# Multivariate Lindeberg-Levy CLT, why assuming $E(||X||^2)<\infty$ instead of $E(XX')<\infty$?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, moments

Multivariate Lindeberg-Levy CLT(demeaned version) states that "Let $\{X_1,...,X_N\}$ be a random sequence with mean zero, if $E(||X_i||^2)<\infty$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ converges in distribution to N(0,$\Omega$) with $\Omega=E(XX')$". Seems to me that what we need is $E(XX')$ being finite. And that the finiteness of $E(||X_i||^2)$ doesn't imply finiteness of $E(XX')$ because we also have the cross-product terms off the diagonal.  My question is why assuming $E(||X_i||^2)<\infty$ is enough.
Let $X(k)$ be the $k-$th element in $X$.
Is it because $E(X(1)X(2))=\{[E(X(1)X(2))]^2\}^{1/2}\leq \{E(X(1))^2E(X(2))^2\}^{1/2}$ by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, so that it suffices to bound $E(||X_i||^2)$?

Comment: The last line answers your question.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much!